# Python: After applying the command "list" on the variable of class filter, this variable is becomes empty

Tags: python, list, filter

it seems i am missing something when applying the command list (Python) on the variable of class filter.
Here is the corresponding code:

```
test_letters = ['o','o', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'j', 'o', 'a']

def filterlet(letter):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    if(letter in vowels):
        return True
    else:
        return False

test_filter = filter(filterlet, test_letters)
l_list = list(test_filter)
print(l_list)
l_list = list(test_filter)
print(l_list)
```

results in

> ['o', 'o', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'a']
>
> []

I am not quit understand why applying the built-in function "list" on filter test "test_filter"
makes it empty (The 2nd call of l_list displays empty output).

Thank you!

Comment: `filter()` returns an iterator. You can only iterate over it once. `list()` does that.

Comment: Might be helpful to read about the behavior of Python generator objects:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should call once again `filter` function with (filterlet, test_letters).

`filter` object becames empty once you convert `filter` object to `list`.

```
test_filter = filter(filterlet, test_letters)
l_list = list(test_filter)
print(l_list)
## call once again with filter function
test_filter = filter(filterlet, test_letters)
l_list = list(test_filter)
print(l_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

> filter(function or None, iterable) --> filter object
>
> Return an iterator yielding those items of iterable for which function(item)
>   is true. If function is None, return the items that are true.

You got the all result from output of filter first time, so you will get nothing after that.